# audio.duration returns Infinity on Safari when mp3 is served from PHP

Tags: php, safari, mp3, html5-audio

So, I have a php script that sends my mp3 file to the audio tag of html5. The problem is that in Safari, the audio.duration tag does not work and returns infinity. If I set the src of the audio directly to the file everything works fine. But I don't want my users to see the path to the file.

Anyways, this is how I'm sending my headers from the PHP.

I have already tried having the content-ranges. That did not help.

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
  $etag = md5(serialize(fstat($fp)));
  fclose($fp);
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
  header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
  header('Content-Length: ' . (string)(filesize($filename)));
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  header('Etag: ' . $etag);

  //GetContentRange($filelength);

  readfile($filename);
  exit;
}
else {
  header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
  echo "no file";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue and added a couple headers. Seems to work for me -

```
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Expires: 0"); 
 header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
 header('Content-Length: ' . $fsize);
 header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $track2play . '"');
 header( 'Content-Range: bytes 0-'.$shortlen.'/'.$fsize); 
 header( 'Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
 header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
 header('Etag: ' . $etag);
```

$fsize is file size and $shortlen =$filesize-1...tested on Safari 5.1.4 and on new iPad...

Answer (score 3):

> Your server must enable Range requests. This is easy to check for by
>   seeing if your server's response includes the Accept-Ranges in its
>   header. Most HTML5 browsers enable seeking to new file positions
>   during a download, so the server must allow the new Range to be
>   requested.
>
> Failure to accept byte Range requests will cause problems on some
>   HTML5 browsers. Often the duration cannot be read from the file as
>   some formats require that the start and end of the file is read to
>   know its duration. Chrome tends to be the browser that has most
>   problems if the Range request is not enabled on the server, but all
>   browsers will have some issue even if it is only that you have to wait
>   for all the media to load before jumping close to the end.

See [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jplayer/nSM2UmnSKKA/bC-l3k0pCPMJ) for a PHP example of how to serve media with Range Requests enabled.

Also, i noticed you are using `No-Cache`..

> Using the server response to disable the local cache of media can
>   cause problems with some HTML5 browsers. This can cause the duration
>   of the media to be unknown.

Answer (score 2):

- Today i wasted most of my time looking into this issue and finally
  came out with an solution. The reason behind why safari returns
  duration as infinity is quite interesting: It appears that Safari
  requests the server twice for playing files. First it sends a range
  request to the server with a range header like this:(bytes:0-1).
- If the server doesn't return the response as a partial content and if it
  returns the entire stream then the safari browser will not set
  audio.duration tag and which result in playing the file only once and
  it can't be played again.
- I made an quick fix to it, in the server side just check the
  header and if it contains a rangeHeader then return it.

  `String rangeHeader = request.getHeader("Range");
  if(rangeHeader != null)
  {
     //just return it
  }`

Comment: Hi @smurf I also see the first call to the audio link with "bytes 0-1" in the Range header. But can you be more specific what you mean by "the return it"? What's it, in this case? I can return one byte by using the Content-Range header in the response. Is that what you mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55621242/2544072

I was wondering the exact same thing. "it" in this case is the "correct" 206 response. See my answer in the link for more information.