# Audio Track Duration Showing "Infinity:NanNan" in Safari Only

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I've got an audio file being played with the basic HTML5 audio tag:

```
 <audio controls itemprop="audio">
  <source src="http://mysite/mus/my_music_file.mp3" />
  </audio>
```

I'm using [Audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/) along with the audio tag for serving up a fallback flash version, as well as a nicely designed player.

In Chrome and Firefox, everything is working as it should, and it's showing the length of the track. Safari is showing: `Infinity:NanNan` in the spot where the song's length should be shown.

I did a search and found a few [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629223/audio-duration-returns-infinity-on-safari-when-mp3-is-served-from-php), but both seem to be talking about PHP headers? I'm not using PHP with my audio files, but it is within a Wordpress theme. Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should indicate the codecs, and not preload

```
<audio preload="none" controls>
    <source src="/path/to/the/source" type="audio/mp3" codecs="mp3"/>
</audio>
```